# Bootstrap submenu not working consistently

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to include two submenu inside a sidebar. However, I have not been getting consistent result for the dropdown. On my 10 attempts of loading/refreshing, the sub-menu drop down only works 4/10 times. Does anyone have an idea why it is producing such results?

There's no error on console either.

Also, I'm using AngularJS to include this sidebar into my main html code.

Code for Sidebar, **sidebar.html**

```
<div class="col-md-2"><!--grid 2 for bootstrap -->
        <div class="sidebar content-box" style="display: block;">
            <ul class="nav">
                <!-- Main menu -->
                <li class="current"><a href=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
                <br>
                <li><a href="calendar.html"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i> Calendar</a></li>
               <br>
                <li><a href="forms.html"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats"></i> Stats</a></li>
               <br>
                 <li class="submenu">
                     <a href="">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i> List
                        <span class="caret pull-right"></span>
                     </a>
                     <!-- Sub menu -->
                     <ul>
                        <li><a href="forms4.html">Sub Function 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="forms5.html">Sub Function 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="forms6.html">Sub Function 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="forms7.html">Sub Function 4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                     <br>

                <li class="submenu">
                     <a href="">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i> Function 5
                        <span class="caret pull-right"></span>
                     </a>
                     <!-- Sub menu -->
                     <ul>
                        <li><a href="forms1.html">Sub Function 5</a></li>
                        <li><a href="forms2.html">Sub Function 6</a></li>
                        <li><a href="forms3.html">Sub Function 7</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
```

AngularJS part to incldue sidebar

```
<!--Include header-->
<div ng-include src="'views/templates/header.html'"></div>
<!--end of header-->
<div class="page-content">
    <div class="row">
    <!-- Insert Side bar-->
    <div ng-include src="'views/templates/sidebar.html'"></div>
    <div class="col-md-10"><!--Main content -->
        <div class="row">
        <!-- to display content here -->
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Not sure what went wrong.

Comment: Would you like to add an example to the plunker?

Comment: Thanks but I've manage to find a workaround by using Angular Directives instead of ng-include. There were probably some conflict between the codes?